# Вывод Smarty в цикле

Tags: ооп, php, smarty

Как вывести в цикле все подключения блоков smarty? Делаю как написано ниже, но чет нифига. Проще говоря, нужно избавиться от кучи записей типа

```
$smarty->assign('title',$arr_meta_tags['title']);
$smarty->assign('keywords',$arr_meta_tags['keywords']);
$smarty->assign('description',$arr_meta_tags['description']);
$smarty->assign('news',$arr_meta_tags['news']);
$smarty->assign('content',$arr_meta_tags['content']);

$news_tpl = $smarty->fetch("news.tpl");
$smarty->assign('blok_news',$news_tpl);
```

и вывести это все в цикле. Плюс к тому, решить проблему неизвестности всех тегов в шаблоне (title, keywords, description и т.д.), чтоб осуществлялся поиск их в шаблоне и производилась замена на нужные блоки

index.php

```
<?php
$dirname = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT_DIR', $dirname);
require_once ROOT_DIR.'/engine/classes/core.class.php';
require_once ROOT_DIR.'/engine/classes/db.class.php';
require_once ROOT_DIR.'/engine/libs/Smarty.class.php';

$db = new DBConnect;
$DBQuery = new DBQuery;

$smarty = new Smarty(); 
$smarty->template_dir='tpl/templates/';
$smarty->compile_dir='tpl/templates_c/';
$smarty->config_dir='tpl/configs/';
$smarty->cache_dir='tpl/cache/';

try{
    $option = 'index';
    if(isset($_GET['section'])){
        $opt = $_GET['section'];
        $path = ROOT_DIR.'/engine/classes/'.$opt.'.class.php';
        if(file_exists($opt)){
            require_once $path;
            if(class_exists($opt)){
                $option = $_GET['section'];
            }
        }       
    }

    $full_path = ROOT_DIR.'/engine/classes/'.$option.'.class.php';
    require_once $full_path;

    $view = new $option();
    $view->getTemplate();

}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

core.class.php

```
<?php
abstract class Core{
    public $template = 'default';

    function replace($tmp_content){ 
    $smarty = new Smarty();

        $replace_tags = preg_match_all("/{\\$(.*)}/", $tmp_content, $array_result);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array_result[0]); $i++){        
            $mb = mb_strtolower($array_result[1][$i]);      
            $path_include = ROOT_DIR.'/tpl/templates/'.$this->template.'/'.$array_result[1][$i].'.tpl';
            if(file_exists($path_include)){
                $text_file = $smarty->fetch($path_include);
                $tmp_content = $smarty->assign('$mb', $text_file);  
            }           
        }
    $smarty->display(ROOT_DIR."/tpl/templates/default/main.tpl");           
    }

    function getTemplate(){
        $template_url = ROOT_DIR.'/tpl/templates/'.$this->template.'/main.tpl';
        if(file_exists($template_url)){
            $tmp = file_get_contents($template_url);
            $tmp = $this->replace($tmp);
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Шаблон не подключен!");
        }
    }

    abstract function getContent();
    abstract function getTitle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$smarty->assign($arr_meta_tags);
```